# Using the result of an Stored procedure in a Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which returns a `Dataset(Table)`. How can I use the result of this stored procedure in a `SELECT` statement?

I need something like this

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM Dummy T0
     INNER JOIN
     (EXEC [dbo].[SPGetResults] '900',300,'USD') T1 
     ON T1.aKey=T0.aKey
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: select into a temp table: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table-valued user-defined function instead.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Marcelo mostly, but if you are set on using a stored procedure, or your stored procedure does anything that affects data, you could create a `#temp` table with the structure of the output of your stored procedure, and then do something like

```
INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC [dbo].[SPGetResults] '900',300,'USD'
```

And then do your joins and selects on the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Marcelo Cantos is the best one. 
Also for distributed queries you can use the following script:

```
USE [master]

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE

USE [YourDB]

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=YourServer ;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC YourDB.YourSchema.YourSP ''YourParameters1'', YourParameters2') AS c
INNER JOIN YourTableOrView ap ON ap.YourPK = c.YourFK
```

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-sql-select-from-stored-procedure-using-openquery-openrowset.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use **Insert Into ... Exec** and store the result into a Temp Table... Then you can join the Temp table in your select statement.

Alternatively as suggested before try converting the SP into a Table valued function.

This link provides much more options for you... http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of table Value user-defined function :

```
create function personSidsByLastName(@lastName varchar(20))
returns table
as 
return 
select personSid from Person where lastName like @lastName

select * from PersonAddress pa where pa.personSid in (select personSid from personSidsByLastName('ali'))
```